# Typekit and IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, typekit

Ive been working on a project for months.  We are using Typekit to load the fonts which works well on pretty much everything. One of the clients keeps sending screenshots where the fonts are off.  I thought the issue was a dated browser. But it turns out the entire network has some fancy IE configuration that blocks the font script.  When I turn on IE 11 high security mode I can replicate the error.

When in IE high Security mode the fonts are displayed as Times New Roman its like 1999 mode. When this mode is enabled and I visit typekit.com and googlefonts.com the websites fonts do not load.

I can not control the network settings. If the fonts are not going to load in this mode then is there a way to load the fonts from somewhere else. Or can I create an alternate websafe scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If your client is blocking fonts, there is not alot you can do but develop a back up fail font in CSS or work with a websafe font to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a couple suggestions on how to tackle this. The only way I've tackled this is just importing the fonts myself. Doing so was faster on my machine too. There was blip of fonts loading. You can use tools such as [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or [Fontie](https://fontie.pixelsvsbytes.com/webfont-generator). Make sure you import Opentype and TrueType as well.